# Download file using CURL

Tags: curl, assembla

I'm using the following CURL to download file from Assembla into the local system. In Curl command, I'm giving both the API key and secret as access token. But it doesn't work. Let me know how I can download the file using CURL.

Following is the curl I'm using to download file:

```
curl -H "X-Api-Key:19f66f38efcdbc" -H "X-Api-Secret:c3eb3856fd08b37f58f490s013wred1" --insecure https://www.assembla.com/code/software-dept/Release/Test.apk?_format=raw
```

Following is the Output that I get when I run the above CURL:

```
$ curl -H "X-Api-Key:19f66f38efcdbc" -H "X-Api-Secret:c3eb3856fd08b37f58f490s013wred1" https://www.assembla.com/code/software-dept/Release/Test.apk
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://www.assembla.com/login">redirected</a
>.</body></html>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the zip bundle of curl from here: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
2. Unzip this anywhere on your PC. (For example: "D:\Program Files\curl-7.33.0-win32")
3. Now open the winow command promt here (Using  "shift + right key")
4. Now paste your curl command on cmd and run it.
5. Use following command.

`curl -H "X-Api-Key:19f66f38efcdbc" -H "X-Api-Secret:c3eb3856fd08b37f58f490s013wred1" --insecure https://api.assembla.com/code/software-dept/Release/Test.apk?_format=raw`

Answer (score 0):

use the command:
curl -H "X-Api-Key:19f66f38efcdbc" -H "X-Api-Secret:c3eb3856fd08b37f58f490s013wred1" --insecure  -o Test.apk https://api.assembla.com/code/software-dept/Release/Test.apk